# Why it is appending the Previous object to array when i append the new object to it using useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([])
const obj = {userName: "ABCD", password: "123245"};
setArr(prevState => [...prevState,obj]);
```

I am writing this to append a new object to array but array is not directly updated. it append the previous object when i want to append the new object to it means it is working one step behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the previous state of the array to add the new object and store it in the state like this:

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
const obj = {userName: "ABCD", password: "123245"};
setArr([...arr, obj]);
```

Comment: But the result is same it is still not update the state directly. it append the previous state when i want to append the new state

Comment: you cannot update it right away. You have to wrap the update inside a function to add the new object and execute the function with an html event as trying to update after initialization is illegal